# My Javascript is not working when having two function?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 functions called on `$(document).ready()` in my Main.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    UpdateValue();
    LocationValue();
});
```

`UpdateValue()` works fine, but when i call `LocationValue()`, it breaks. It seems to be due to the `getWards()` function called in `LocationValue()`.

Here are the two functions:

```
function UpdateValue() {
$(document.body).on("change", ".Quantity", function () {
    var ProID = $(this).attr("data");
    var Quatity = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", url: "/Cart/UpdateValue", data: { ProID: ProID, quantity: Quatity },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".cart_box").html(data);
            }
        }
            );
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
    });
}
function LocationValue() {
    $("#City").change(function () {
        var cityID = $("#City").val();
        alert(cityID);
        getWards(cityID);
    });
}
function getWards(cityID) {
    alert("in show");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Checkout/Wards",
        data: {CityID: cityID},
        dataType:"json",        
        type:"POST",
        error:function()
        {
            alert("An error occured");
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            var items="";
            $.each(data, function(i,item))
            {
            items+="<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Ward").html(items);
        }
    });
}
```

`alert(cityID)` in `LocationValue()` only shows correctly if I comment out the call to `getWards()`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What errors do you get? Provide a line number if you can.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Comment: UpdateValue() has extra  });

Comment: Not error, my js file is not working.

Comment: @Luffy *What* isn't working? What functionality is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getWards(cityID) {
    alert("in show");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Checkout/Wards",
        data: {CityID: cityID},
        dataType:"json",        
        type:"POST",
        error:function()
        {
            alert("An error occured");
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            var items="";
            $.each(data, function(i,item))
```

^^ You have one too many ')'... delete the last ) and it might work.

```
            {
            items+="<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Ward").html(items);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, it's my fault. I'm newbie in jquery, so i confused about {}().

Comment: We all have been there =) welcome aboard.. could you checkmark the answer as correct for historical sake?

Answer (score 0):

You have an syntax error in the method

```
function getWards(cityID) {
    alert("in show");
    $.ajax({
        url : "/Checkout/Wards",
        data : {
            CityID : cityID
        },
        dataType : "json",
        type : "POST",
        error : function() {
            alert("An error occured");
        },
        success : function(data) {
            var items = "";
            $.each(data, function(i, item) { // an extra ) was here
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value
                + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Ward").html(items);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It works. But i don't understand why has varible i in function(i, item). "i" is not used.

Comment: @Luffy that is the syntax specification for the callback method of `$.each()`, those parameters are passed by the caller of the method - as a user we don't have control of that

Comment: `$("#City").change(function () {
        var cityID = $("#City").val();
        if (cityID == null) {
            $("Ward").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $("Ward").prop("disabled", false);
            getWards(cityID);
        }
    });` I'm trying disable or return to Optional Label the second dropdown when the first dropdown has no value or in Optional Label. But this code doesn't work, i have set $("Ward").prop("disabled", true);